# nginx infinite 302 Found redirect loop

Tags: nginx, redirect, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx to map multiple domains to google app engine.
in this specific case i map multiple domains to the **same tenant**. 
there is a configuration in my code that knows which domain is the main domain and when a request comes in i check if the host is the main domain and if it isn't i redirect to the main domain.

for example lets say `www.aaa.com` is the domain set as default

```
aaa.com     -> www.aaa.com
www.bbb.com -> www.aaa.com
ccc.com     -> www.aaa.com
...
```

what happens randomly from time to time is that a javascript url goes into a redirect loop on nginx. 
note that the request never hits appengine. nginx is creating this `302 Found` loop.
this happened 2 times in the past 2 weeks.

the request path looks like `www.aaa.com/22/foobar.js` where the first part of the path is the version number of the javascript file.

a css file with the same uri format `www.aaa.com/22/foobar.css` won't have this redirect loop.

if i deploy a new version the file will server correctly again. so deploying a version `23` and accessing `www.aaa.com/23/foobar.js` would work again.
also if i use a cachebuster on the request like `www.aaa.com/22/foobar.js?345`
restarting nginx or even restarting the machine where nginx is running does not help. 
setting up a new machine with the same exact configuration serves the file with no problem.

so what could cause this redirect loop? 
how could i get rid of it once it happens? 
is there a cache on nginx (i know nginx is not caching by default) i dont know about?
does the machine maybe cache those redirects?

here my nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 2;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_max_size 1024;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    # enable gzip compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 4 32k;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css;
    gzip_vary on;


    server {
        server_name www.aaa.com;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host tenantname.myappid.appspot.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header NexHost $scheme://$host;
            proxy_redirect http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/ /;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }
    }


    server {
        server_name aaa.com;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host tenantname.myappid.appspot.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header NexHost $scheme://$host;
            proxy_redirect http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/ /;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name www.bbb.com;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host tenantname.myappid.appspot.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header NexHost $scheme://$host;
            proxy_redirect http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/ /;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }
    }



    server {
        server_name bbb.com;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host tenantname.myappid.appspot.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header NexHost $scheme://$host;
            proxy_redirect http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/ /;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }
    }



    server {
        server_name www.ccc.com;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host tenantname.myappid.appspot.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header NexHost $scheme://$host;
            proxy_redirect http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/ /;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }
    }


    server {
        server_name ccc.com;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host tenantname.myappid.appspot.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header NexHost $scheme://$host;
            proxy_redirect http://tenantname.myappid.appspot.com/ /;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }
    }


    server {
        server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.maindomain\.com$;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://$sub.myappid.appspot.com/$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host $sub.myappid.appspot.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header NexHost $scheme://$host;
            proxy_redirect http://$sub.myappid.appspot.com/ /;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        location / {
            root /etc/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i solved this problem by redirecting from nginx rather than from the backend.
while the issue is solved by now i still didn't figure out why this redirect loop was happening in the first place.

every hint would be helpful.